# Does "Daddy is home" sound natural?

Tags: grammaticality

> "I am home."

How to change "I" to "Daddy"?

Daddy is home?

Comment: The contractions "I'm home" and "Daddy's home" would be more normal in everyday speech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Daddy is home" is perfectly natural. You may have heard about sentences like "Daddy misses you so much" "Daddy likes you so much" when talking to the kids, It looks lovely.

Answer (score 6):

You would only say this to a small child who called you Daddy.  I have daughters who are 7 and 9 who do call me Daddy, and when I come home and greet them I would say "I'm home."  They would know me from my voice, and at that age they would feel like I was treating them like babies if I referred to myself as Daddy.

That said, their mother might say to them, upon my arrival, "Daddy is home," and it would be perfectly natural.  It is *referring to myself* as "Daddy" that is unusual except with small children.

It would be similar to you and I talking and me saying, "Jason is having a nice conversation."  That might be a true statement, and if someone else said it, it would be perfectly natural, but referring to myself in the third person is strange in most situations.

Answer (score 3):

Although "Daddy is home" is correct English, I personally think it sounds a bit robotic and strange as a whole sentence, especially if being spoken. "Daddy's home" would sound more natural to me (although I'd also prefer "I'm home" if a natural sound is the aim).

Examples where "Daddy is home" works better (in my opinion) would be things like:

"We'll leave when Daddy comes home"

"Daddy *is* home!"

where there's emphasis on the "is"